# 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' How to fix? Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, compiler-errors

I'm trying to put form variables into a database, however, I'm still VERY new at these things and I'm just trying random copy pasted code from the internet to learn.
This is the only thing giving me problems

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;
@using WebMatrix.WebData;
@using System.Data.SqlClient;


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Recruta";

}

@{ 

    var Nome = "";
    var Email = "";
    var Tel = "";
    var Adress = "";
    var Gender = "";

    Nome = Request.Form["Nome"];
    Email = Request.Form["Email"];
    Tel = Request.Form["Tel"];
    Adress = Request.Form["Adress"];
    Gender = Request.Form["Gender"];

    var db = Database.Open("Usuarios");
    var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (Nome, Email, Tel, Adress, Gender) Values(@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)";
    db.Execute(insertCommand, Nome, Email, Tel, Adress, Gender);
    Response.Redirect("~/Usuarios");
        }
```

This is the information given by vs:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The database 'c:\users\softinsa\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Best_prototype_01\Best_prototype_01\App_Data\Usuarios.mdf' cannot be opened because it is version 851. This server supports version 706 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

Cannot attach the file 'c:\users\softinsa\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Best_prototype_01\Best_prototype_01\App_Data\Usuarios.mdf' as database 'c:\users\softinsa\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Best_prototype_01\Best_prototype_01\App_Data\Usuarios.mdf'.
```

And this is where the error lies apparently:

```
  db.Execute(insertCommand, Nome, Email, Tel, Adress, Gender);
```

I apologize if I'm posting a dumb question, as I said, I'm still very fresh in asp.net and it's endevours.

I appreciate you reading this and hopefully you can help.

**EDIT:** 
I tried using the solutions on [The database cannot be opened because it is version 782. This server supports version 706 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346647/the-database-cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-version-782-this-server-supports-ve)
and none of them worked for me, I'm using VS Community edition 2015, by default the connections are already (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB so that isn't the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, never ever code business logic inside your ASP.NET MVC views.

Second, the exception is quite clear:

> The database '...' cannot be opened because it is version 851. This server supports version 706 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

You don't have the right version of SQL Server running on that system. You are trying to open a newer database file format version than you have installed. Either install the correct version of SQL Server, or downgrade the database file format.

This [might be related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36773312/993547) to your use of Visual Studio 2015 update 2.

Comment: It's WebMatrix, they [actually encourage putting logic in views in their tutorials](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/5-working-with-data). Then again, the MVC tutorials use Entity models as View models...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how would I go about downgrading the databse file format? I have no clue which version of SQL Server I need to have in order to fix the error, so I think downgrading would be the safer approach.

Comment: I guess you can do that from SQL Server Management Studio, if you have installed it.