# Can't connect to LocalDB from Visual Studio 2015 due to database version 852

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, localdb

When I try to connect to the database, to which I was previously able to connect, I get the following error:

[image]

I tried to solve this by looking up other stackoverflow questions and online resources, but without success. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 852 is the internal version number for Sql Server 2016, 851 is not documented as far as I know. Probably your current installation of Sql Server 2016 needs some upgrade or patch to bring the internal version to 852.

Comment: The following post may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699309/sql-local-database-cannot-be-opened   Although the referenced versions in the post are different from your situation, the resolution is likely very similar.

Comment: This post as well: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5a3bc1e-6fc8-4232-8d77-e76d87341a6c/server-explorer-error?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade  -- with the takeaway quote being: "_The database version 851 sounds like a CTP; if it is so then you have to update to RTM Version = 852._"

Comment: I experienced same problem as I created by myself the database mdf file with localDB 2014. However, because my development strategy changed and then I changed Server matters. And this message showed. The solution is as the message says. It seems the mdf file was created from higher version Server. I tried and spent times but there was no alternative way but to use the right version Server. localDB is not heavy and you can try easily. And be sure localDB doesn't support TCP/IP networking only in case you want because it is why called as localDB

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments, I updated to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 through Tools -> Extensions and Updates and it fixed the problem and now the versions match